# subset and replace all nth elements from an array of vectors

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I am trying to generate a matrix where each element is a vector of length 2 and then fill the vectors automatically. What I have so far is:

```
dat <- matrix(list(vector("numeric",2)),3,3)
dat

##      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
## [1,] Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2
## [2,] Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2
## [3,] Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2
```

I want to fill this empty matrix so that it looks something like this:

```
       [[,1]]   [[,2]]   [[,3]]     
[[1,]] [1] 1 1  [1] 1 2  [1] 1 3
[[2,]] [1] 2 1  [1] 2 2  [1] 2 3
[[3,]] [1] 3 1  [1] 3 2  [1] 3 3
```

I can subset and replace each element manually with the code `dat[[1,1]] <- c(1,1)` and I can subset all the first vector elements of `dat` with the code `sapply(dat,"[", 1)`, but I can't then replace these vector elements with the desired values, e.g. `sapply(dat,"[", 1) <- rep(1:3,3)` (returns `could not find function "sapply<-"` error).

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest you use a 3-D array instead?

```
ary <- array(1:18, dim=c(3,3,2))
ary
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   10   13   16
# [2,]   11   14   17
# [3,]   12   15   18
```

Reassignment of a single "pair". Note the trailing comma, similar to how `mtcars[1,]` returns all columns from the first row.

```
ary[1,1,] <- c(1, 1)
ary
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   13   16
# [2,]   11   14   17
# [3,]   12   15   18
```

To replace all first-values:

```
ary[,,1] <- rep(1:3, 3)
ary
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    2    2    2
# [3,]    3    3    3
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   13   16
# [2,]   11   14   17
# [3,]   12   15   18
```

In order to apply something over the matrix of paired values, you can use `apply(ary, 1:2, ...)`, such as:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(1,3), ylim=c(1,18))
apply(ary, c(1,2), function(pts) points(pts[1], pts[2]))
```

When you look at the `MARGIN` argument (`c(1,2)` here) of `apply`, it is saying "apply a function for each row,column 'set' of the data". When looking at a simple 2-D matrix, a margin of `c(1,2)` iterates the function over each individual value. In a 3-D array, it applies the function over each "pipe" of the matrix.

That `apply` call is equivalent to this sequence of function calls:

```
points(1, 1)
points(2, 11)
points(3, 12)
points(1, 13)
points(2, 14)
points(3, 15)
points(1, 16)
points(2, 17)
points(3, 18)
```

(This example could easily be accomplished with `plot(ary[,,1], ary[,,2])`, but that doesn't necessarily answer your need for a function that accepts the pair as a single argument. Similarly with `mapply(points, ary[,,1], ary[,,2])`.)

If your consuming function takes a *vector* of values, then perhaps this will work:

```
apply(ary, c(1,2), yourfunc)
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this, but unfortunately I want to use each matrix element as the input for a function which needs a pair of numerical arguments. Should have specified this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide an example of this, it isn't clear to me. More the point, doesn't `func(ary[1,1,])` do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes that will probably work. If I am trying to apply `func` using `lapply` the other form is preferable, but maybe I can use `mapply` in combination with your idea. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: blklempay, does this answer your question?